# Handling back press in a page in windows phone 8.1RT

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1

In one of page in my app i have to show pop up box after i show it if user press back button without removing pop up box then i have to handle that box(may be removing) first and in next back press i want to navigate to previous page.Its Like when keypad is open first back press will minimize it and in second press page navigate to previous page. How can i do that?

I tried handling BackPressed event in page level but it doesn't work. Code here

```
        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if(isOPen)
        {
            isOPen=false;
            Storyboard2.Begin();
            parda.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

isOPen save the status weather popup is currently open or not.

**Update:**

Here is what i did. As usual first landing on mainpage and then navigation to second page, in second page i have to pop up a grid with textboxes for popup visibility i handle it from check and uncheck event of toggleappbarbutton.

code is simple:

```
        private void togglr_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isOPen = true;
        parda.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Storyboard1.Begin();
    }

    private void togglr_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isOPen = flase;
        parda.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Storyboard2.Begin();
    }
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

In the if condition I don't see setting the `isOpen` to `false`

this way your if never gets in the else block

Comment: @Janak try putting the e.Handled = true; at the top of each block

Comment: Still not work. It executes if block but also page navigate back and in isOPen == false it works fine.

Comment: @Janak the code posted looks fine, maybe the problem is in another part of your code, show us more!

Comment: Some other class may be subscribed to the HardwareButtons_BackPressed which inturn maybe executing the back command, its always better to unsubscribe such events.

Answer (score 0):

I write logic on OnNavigatingFrom method(by overriding) like this

```
        protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(isOPen)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Storyboard2.Begin();
            parda.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

And it works fine now.